# how to encrypt /decrypt pdf or doc file in c# without changing its format

Tags: c#

by using doc or pdf libraries i cant encrypt file along  with its format i m only able to read text file from doc and store it in string and pass to encrypt function and decrypt function

1. i want to read text from doc along with its format
2. pass it to encrypt decrypt function
3. store decrypted text in doc file along with its format

.

```
else if (comboBox1.Text == ".doc")
{
    var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = application.Documents.Open(textBox1.Text);

    // Loop through all words in the document.
    int count = document.Words.Count;
    string s2 = " ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        // Write the word.
        string text = document.Words[i].Text;
        Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text);
        s2 = s2 + text;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(s2);
    txtSend.Text = s2;
    // Close word.
    application.Quit();
}

string plainText=txtSend.Text;

CryptLib _crypt = new CryptLib();
//string plainText = "This is the text to be encrypted";
String iv = CryptLib.GenerateRandomIV(16); //16 bytes = 128 bits
string key = CryptLib.getHashSha256("my secret key", 31); //32 bytes = 256 bits
MessageBox.Show(plainText);//////////////////////
String cypherText = _crypt.encrypt(plainText, key, iv);
Console.WriteLine("iv=" + iv);
Console.WriteLine("key=" + key);
Console.WriteLine("Cypher text=" + cypherText);
MessageBox.Show(cypherText);
textBox1.Text = cypherText;
Console.WriteLine("Plain text =" + _crypt.decrypt(cypherText, key, iv));
MessageBox.Show(_crypt.decrypt(cypherText, key, iv));
textBox2.Text = _crypt.decrypt(cypherText, key, iv);
```

Comment: Why don't you just encrypt all file content? No need to read doc format, use binary stream of file.

Comment: thanks for the reply i found my answer yesterday i did the same thing you said and its done again thanks